# LinkedBlockingQueue with one element - Reader/Writer Race Condition

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

LinkedBlockingQueue uses two separate ReentrantLocks, **putLock** and **takeLock**. This enables one reader and one writer to access the queue at the same time using the following methods:

```
1) poll()
2) take()
3) put()
4) offer()
```

Lets say a linkedBlockingQueue has only one element. poll()/take() uses takeLock and put()/offer() uses putLock.
I see there will be a race condition when poll() tries to remove the only element and put() tries to add another element because **one reader and one writer thread** will be accessing node datastructure at the same time.

So, does this mean LinkedBlockingQueue is not completely thread-safe?

Comment: there is package-private method `fullyLock()` that ensure no race condition when necessary (eg. called from `remove`, `contains`, `clear` , ...) `So, does this mean LinkedBlockingQueue is not completely thread-safe` - unless mentioned in javadocs collections from `java.util.concurrent` are thread-safe